# What does the Accepted/Rejected mean?

Tags: mining-pools, terminology, mining-pool-shares, btcguild

I'm using a Bitcoin Miner on Btc Guild. It's showing `12 Accepted, 0 Rejected`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

This means the pool has accepted 12 shares from your miner.  It indicates that you have configured the application correctly and the pool is accepting your workers shares.